# Windows 10 Universal app won't show soft keyboard when focus on input areas

Tags: keyboard, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10, virtual-keyboard

I am building a Windows 10 Uiversal App Web App (Project Westminster). And I am testing it on my local device, which is a Surface Pro 3 running Windows 10. The app is running somoothly and as expected in desktop mode, but when I detach the keyboard and switch the device to tablet mode, the soft keyboard won't show up when I focus on the input areas, textareas etc. So I can't even login etc.

However, if I run it on a Windows Phone emulator, the keyboard does show up when input got focused.

Is there some configurations I need to set for my App so that the soft keyboard would show as expected on tablets? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is Windows 10 then. In Windows 10 there is "Tablet Mode" and "PC Mode", 
This is what you need to do :

1. Set it to "Tablet Mode"
2. In the source code set the focus to the textBox

example : textBox1.Focus(true);

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that this question got older, i will share my knowledge about this.

> The touch keyboard does not automatically display if a hardware
>   keyboard is connected, or the device is in Desktop mode and "Show the
>   touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard
>   attached" is set to "Off" in Settings -> Devices -> Typing.

To show the soft keyboard when a text field is focused, Please make sure the above setting is enabled and no hardware keyboard is connected.

Please go through this microsoft sample in which they have clearly explained about this,

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TouchKeyboard

I hope this helps.